# Как задать программно размеры таблицы на всю страницу браузера?

Tags: c#

Если таблица создана в коде

```
var T = new Table();
...
T.Style.Add("width", "100%"); // не прокатывает
this.controls.Add(T);
```

Comment: @VKonstantin о каких таблицах идет речь? Что за технология/фреймворк?

Comment: @VKonstantin, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.